# Kafka enable.auto.commit = true and commitSync() is used

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

It is recommended that `commitSync()` should only be used when `enable.auto.commit` is set to `false`. But we used `commitSync()` and forgot to set `enable.auto.commit` to `false`. So I wanted to know what would be happening in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [`enable.auto.commit`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs) is set to `True` then the consumer's offset are periodically committed in the background. On the other hand, [`commitSync()`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/consumer.html#synchronous-commits) is a blocking call that allows committing offsets manually.

In your case, the offsets will be committed in both cases:

- Every time you call `commitSync()`
- Every `N` ms where `N` is a configurable parameter (`auto.commit.interval.ms`)

Comment: When using spring-kafka, we recommend setting it to `false`; the container will commit the offsets in a more deterministic fashion with `AckMode.BATCH` (default) or `AckMode.RECORD`. Recent versions of spring-kafka set it to false by default (unless explicitly set).